при переходе на функцию process_vod_prav_uk_step водил текст наживаю кнопку yes у меня ничего не происходит
import telebot
from telebot import types


group_id = -4283368729
user_dict = {}

# bot = telebot.TeleBot('', threaded=False)  # официальный бот
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')  # тестовый бот
print('bot started')


class User:
    pass


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton(" Русский")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton(' English')
    markup.add(btn1, btn2)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, " Выберите язык /  Choose your language", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def message_reply(message):
    if message.text == " English":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("id cards")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("check/documents")
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("other")
        markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choose what you need', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == " Русский":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("удостоверение личности")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("чеки/документы")
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("другое")
        markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите что вам нужно', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == "id cards":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("driver license")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("passport")
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("back")
        markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Select a specific category', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == "удостоверение личности":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("водительские права")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("паспорт")
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("назад")
        markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберете определенную категорию', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == "назад":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("удостоверение личности")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("чеки/документы")
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("другое")
        markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите что вам нужно', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == "back":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("id cards")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("check/documents")
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("other")
        markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choose what you need', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == "чеки/документы":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Назад')
        nnn = 'Опишите что вам нужно'
        markup.add(item2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, nnn, reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_vod_prav_step)

    elif message.text == "да":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("удостоверение личности")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("чеки/документы")
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("другое")
        markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
        bot.send_message(group_id, vodi_pav)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ожидайте с вами скоро свяжутся', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == "yes":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("id cards")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("check/documents")
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("other")
        markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
        bot.send_message(group_id, vodi_pav)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Expect to be contacted soon', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == "нет":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("удостоверение личности")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("чеки/документы")
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("другое")
        markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите что вам нужно', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == "другое":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Назад')
        nnn = 'Опишите что вам нужно'
        markup.add(item2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, nnn, reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_vod_prav_step)

    elif message.text == "паспорт":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Назад')
        nnn = 'Опишите что вам нужно'
        markup.add(item2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, nnn, reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_vod_prav_step)

    elif message.text == "other":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Back')
        nnn = 'Describe what you need'
        markup.add(item2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, nnn, reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_vod_prav_uk_step)

    elif message.text == "not":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("id cards")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("check/documents")
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("other")
        markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choose what you need', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == "check/documents":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Back')
        nnn = 'Describe what you need'
        markup.add(item2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, nnn, reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_vod_prav_uk_step)

    elif message.text == "passport":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Back')
        nnn = 'Describe what you need'
        markup.add(item2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, nnn, reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_vod_prav_uk_step)

    elif message.text == "водительские права":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("назад")
        markup.add(item3)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напишие страну для прав, с зоглавной буквы \n Катигории и имя фамилию '
                                          'отчество \n Датурождения и получения прав', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_vod_prav_step)

    elif message.text == "driver license":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("back")
        markup.add(item3)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Write the country for the license, with a capital letter \n Categories and '
                                          'first name, last name, patronymic \n Date of birth and license',
                         reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_vod_prav_uk_step)


def process_vod_prav_step(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("да")
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton("нет")
    markup.add(item2, item3)
    global vodi_pav
    user_first_name = str(message.from_user.username)
    vodi_pav = message.text + ' user id @' + user_first_name
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Все верно?', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, message_reply)


def process_vod_prav_uk_step(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("yas")
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton("not")
    markup.add(item2, item3)
    global vodi_pav
    user_first_name = str(message.from_user.username)
    vodi_pav = message.text + '  user id @' + user_first_name
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Is everything correct?', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, message_reply)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)


Зачем Вы предоставили весь код проекта, включая токен и лишние строчки? Укажите где именно возникает проблема, опишите её детально и предоставьте только необходимое.

Ещё у вас опечатка в слове item2 = types.KeyboardButton("yas"), должно быть yes.
